# InApp Purchase in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have create new product in itunesconnect.apple.com for InAppPurchase.

but there display following warning message "Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary."

and "Submit for review" button is disable.

So, Please suggest when i create the new product for InAppPurchase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had same problem. What you have to do here is due to first time submission of application in app purchase, **upload your app to itunes and reject it from the binary details**.

After rejecting when you are again being ready for uploading you will have **list of In-App purchase at the bottom** section where you can select suitable In-App purchase from there.

Hope this helps.